# Errors while replacing adresses on localhost xampp Error: There has been a critical error on this website.Learn more about debugging in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wp-cli

Errors i get while replacing:
First:
Error: There has been a critical error on this website.Learn more about debugging in WordPress. There has been a critical error on this website.

Second:
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: unserialize(): Argument #1 ($data) must be of type string, array given in phar://C:/wp-cli/wp-cli.phar/vendor/wp-cli/search-replace-command/src/WP_CLI/SearchReplacer.php:86
Version of php:
[Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPlZL.png)

When i am trying to replace adresses with this comand:

wp search-replace https://example.com http://example.com --all-tables --verbose

I am getting this errors above.

Answer (score 0):

The WP-CLI expetcs your search and replace parameters to be a string. Currently (most probably because of colons `:`) the CLI thinks your url's are multiple strings and puts them into an array.

If you wrap each url into quotes `'` the problem should be fixed.

`wp search-replace 'https://example.com' 'http://example.com' --all-tables --verbose`

Comment: still the same :/

Comment: Used the code like it is in my answer and it's running just fine. Can you tell me your WP CLI version `wp --version` and the php-version `php -v`?

Comment: I solved problem, different version of php was installed on cmd terminal and xmapp shell i changed php folder in xampp and it is working but, anyway thanks for help :)